# Ошибка при сериализации

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой при сериализации происходящей в только что созданный файл.

Вот код:

```
private void PrepareLaunch()
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Data";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    if (!File.Exists(path + "\\List.xml"))
    {
        File.Create(path + "\\List.xml");
        XmlFile.Serialize<ObservableCollection<MyClass>>(path + "\\List.xml", new ObservableCollection<MyClass>());
    }
}
```

Статический класс `XmlFile` - это просто обвёртка для более удобного использования сериализации/десериализации, код ниже.

```
public static class XmlFile
{
    public static void Serialize<T>(string path, T o)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(fs, o);
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
    {
        T res;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            res = (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(fs);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: при выполнении функции `XmlFile.Serialize` возникает ошибка с сообщением о том, что файл занят другим процессом. Не сложно догадаться, что речь о процессе выполнявшемся до, а значит - `File.Create(path + "\\List.xml");`, но вот как решить эту проблему - я не знаю.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще создавать файл? У вас в "обвертке" вашей есть такая вещь, как `FileMode`, поставьте `OpenOrCreate` и будет сам создавать, если файла нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хахаха, чёрт, всё гениальное просто... Как же я сам забыл об этом)) Спасибо)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У FileStream есть [FileMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) - один из них, это OpenOrCreate.

> OpenOrCreate - Указывает, что операционная система должна открыть файл, при его наличии; в противном случае — должен быть создан новый файл.

То есть другими словами, ваш `File.Create()` лишний в данном случае и достаточно переключить FileMode.